# Full body haar cascade detections using OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi4, haar-classifier

I am trying to detect persons using `opencv` `python` with `haarcascade`. I am using `haarcascade_fullbody.xml` and below is the code:

```
import cv2

body_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_fullbody.xml')

frame = cv2.imread('2.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

bodies = body_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2, 3)

for (x, y, w, h) in bodies:
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow('Humans', frame)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Input image (taken from google):

[image]

Its not able to detect persons in the image file. I am not sure if I have done something wrong or not. I have to run this on `raspberry pi` due to which I am using `haarcascading` otherwise I would have used `mobilenet ssd` models which works more accurately than haarcascade. Can anyone please tell me how can I use haarcascade to detect persons. Is there any other way of detecting persons on raspberry.?

Comment: You could try using `HOGDescriptor` instead.

Comment: @yudhiesh any links to any article/documentation.?

Comment: [This article should help](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/09/pedestrian-detection-opencv/)